# Generate test data using Oracle PL/SQL developer

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper, test-data

I want to test some schemas and indexes, and I was wondering if there is a functionality in PL/SQL Developer that can generate test data (so I won't have to create sequences and loops to insert data in the tables).

Comment: I don't believe there is I'm afraid.

Comment: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Oracle_Row_Generator_Techniques

Comment: AskTom: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2151576678914

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Loops and PL/SQL aren't always necessary; this trick might be helpful:

```
insert into emp(id, name, salary)
select rownum, 'Employee ' || to_char(rownum), dbms_random.value(2, 9) * 1000
from dual
connect by level <= 100;
```

will generate 100 records, named Employee 1 through Employee 100 with random "round" salaries between 2000 and 9000.

The two main techniques are:

1. Use of `connect by level <= n` to generate n rows in a query on dual.
2. Use of `dbms_random` package; there's also a very useful function `dbms_random.string` which can be used -- like its name suggests -- to generate random strings of a certain length containing certain characters.

Comment: DBMS_RANDOM.string('x',10) for strings